# image flickers when dragged around with mouse lua love2d

Tags: image, lua, love2d

I'm using lua and [love2d](https://love2d.org/) to create a simple image viewer, and I'm having trouble dragging the images around with my cursor. The code is:

```
function love.update()
    local mX, mY = love.mouse.getPosition()

    for _, v in pairs(imgs) do
        local collX = v.x < mX and mX < v.intX
        local collY = v.y < mY and mY < v.intY
        local hover = collX and collY
        if love.mouse.isDown(1) and hover then
            v.x = mX - v.width * 0.5
            v.y = mY - v.height * 0.5
            v.intX = v.x + v.width
            v.intY = v.y + v.height
        end
    end
end

function love.draw()
    for _, v in pairs(imgs) do
        love.graphics.draw(v.src, v.x, v.y)
    end
end
```

for the drawing part. THIS CODE WORKS FINE, but since `v.x` and `v.y` (the position of the image that you're dragging) is set to the mouse position - half the w/h of the image. That means that if I grab an image it will always grab from the center, and the center of the image will "teleport" to the mouse. I want it so that i can grab the image from wherever my mouse is, and then move it around. So i tried to set the `v.x` and `v.y` to the mouse position - the previous `v.x` and `v.y`:

```
v.x = mX - v.x
v.y = mY - v.y
```

[But the output is this.](https://i.imgur.com/4aGJSUD.mp4)

 
[how i want it](https://i.imgur.com/OE4t5Bf.mp4)

Comment: When first grabbing, remember the offset relative to your anchor point (e.g. left top, or center, `offset = mX - v.x`). Then your position is `v.x = mX + offsetX`.